# When bundled with rollupjs seeing the "require is not defined" error

Tags: rollupjs

Trying to bundle a library here with rollupjs and to add that to an example HTML like like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="/dist/videomail-client.js"></script>
        <script>
            var VideomailClient = require('videomail-client')

            ...
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But then, I see this error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

The whole rollupjs config can be seen here https://github.com/binarykitchen/videomail-client/blob/feature/rollupjs/env/dev/rollup.config.js

Using the cjs format because it is supposed to come with that `require` function, doesn't it? Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

`format: 'cjs'` means 'create a bundle that can be used in a CommonJS environment' — i.e. either Node.js or a bundler. There's no `require` function in the browser.

You should use `format: 'iife'` or `format: 'umd'` with `moduleName: 'VideomailClient'`, then use it like so:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="/dist/videomail-client.js"></script>
        <script>
            var videomailClient = new VideomailClient(...);

            ...
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does that mean, iife and umd would pollute global window with `VideomailClient`? isn't that bad practice?

anyway, i gave it a try with both formats but am seeing this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: VideomailClient is not defined` 

.. furthermore with `iife` i can see window global has a VideomailClient entry but is `undefined`.

Comment: No, it's not bad practice, it's *how libraries work*. If the consumer of VideomailClient wants to consume it via a module system (AMD, or their own bundler) then UMD will let them do that. If they want to use it via a `<script>` tag then of course it needs to be accessible as a property of `window`. As far as the `undefined` thing goes, you'll need to provide a [repro](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/88c5fc2ac6dc941b22e7996af05d70ff).

Comment: Mmhhh, interesting. Ok I see. Will stick to `iife` then. Yeah, about the `undefined` problem, to repro, just git clone https://github.com/binarykitchen/videomail-client/tree/feature/rollupjs and run `yarn start`... and you'll see this in the console

Comment: 'Run my entire project and somehow figure out what the problem is' is *not* a repro. [Read this document](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/88c5fc2ac6dc941b22e7996af05d70ff), and prepare a **minimal** reproduction. In the course of doing so it's highly likely that you'll find the problem.

Comment: True that. Already have found and narrowed down the cause of that `undefined` problem to this one: `node_modules/websocket-stream/stream.js   Could not load stream (imported by /home/michael-heuberger/code/videomail-client/node_modules/websocket-stream/stream.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'stream'`... trying to find out more from here ...